# Not Recognized as a valid datetime. Unknown word starting at index 0

Tags: c#

I am trying calculate the timespan between two listbox. 
This my code..

```
for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
{
    DateTime z = DateTime.Parse(listBox2.Items.ToString());
    DateTime c = DateTime.Parse(listBox3.Items.ToString());
    TimeSpan w = c - z;
}
```

Comment: `Items` is a collection and the `ToString` will give you the name of the type, not the values in the collection.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, I think you need indexer to get item not collection of items in your for loop.

Comment: Also, why are you iterating x over the indexes of `listBox1.Items`, but then working with `listBox2` and `listBox3`?  Are all 3 list boxes guaranteed to have the same number of items?

Comment: And in the end, you are assigning the difference to `w` over and over, when it eventually only equals the difference between the last two dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need some thing like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
{
    DateTime z = DateTime.Parse(listBox2.Items[x].ToString());
    DateTime c = DateTime.Parse(listBox3.Items[x].ToString());
    TimeSpan w = c.Subtract(z);
}
```

Also, your ListBoxes items should be the same count

Comment: makes sense to use the index, but it's still only essentially using the last item.